# Is it possible to call method of an Abstract class in derived class or any other class

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

Is it possible to call method of an Abstract class in derived class or any other class. My code is below, I want to call Abstr's `Describe()` method in Program's Main method.
Is it possible? if answer is yes how?

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        //I want to call the Describe() method here, how do i do that
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class Abstr
{
    public void Describe()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever try it actually and got a problem ?

Comment: Nobody can help you if you keep changing your example code.  Also it helps to post the text of any errors you get.  Saves us chasing our tails trying to find an answer when you have information that could help.

Comment: this is not fair, i did not expected this from your site

Comment: @Pradeep - What exactly did you expect?  You have dozens of questions so this isn't the first time you have asked for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your method is not static, you need to initialize a variable from that abstract class and call that method from it. To do that you may inherit the abstract class by concreate class and then call that method. Note that the abstract class can't be initialized throw a constructor like `Abstr abstr = new Abstr();` is not valid. So:

```
public abstract class Abstr
{
    public void Describe()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class Concrete : Abstr
{
   /*Some other methods and properties..*/ 
}

class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Abstr abstr = new Concrete();
        abstr.Describe();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do Concrete abstr = new Concrete();

Comment: @Ramhound: I want to show hem how to initialize\use `Abstr` instance.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `Abstr.Describe()` directly. It is a static method, so the class being abstract shouldn't matter.

### Edit

Now that the code in the question has been edited and the `static` keyword is removed on the methods, this answer does no longer apply.

Comment: What if it is a non static class

Comment: The *method* is static, so it can be access without having an instance of the class. Any class can contain static methods, but *static classes* can *only* contain static methods and not any other methods.

Comment: in case both Main and Describe are non static

Comment: In the code you posted both `Main` and `Describe` have the `static` keyword so those method are static.

Comment: And thus made my answer obsolete. If you want help, please make sure that you post relevant code, preferably by *testing* it and validating that you get the described error and then copy-pasting that exact code here.

Comment: @Pradeep: Because I don't feel like it. I'm spending my own, unpaid spare time here to help because I like being helpful. When you changed your question I got enough. I don't feel like helping you any more, so I won't.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: is it possible to call method of an Abstract class in derived
>   class?

A: Sure, as long as it's public, protected (and the same class or a subclass), or internal (and the same assembly)

> Q: Any other class?

A: Sure, as long as it's public or internal (and the same assembly)

Good link:
http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/internal-and-protected/

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to call

EDIT:

Original post was changed, so this answer is not valid.

```
 Abstr.Describe();
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible code : [here](http://pastebin.com/Sygqwqki)

This works for non static method as well

Comment: can we create instance of abstract class using new key word? :)

Comment: nope but since I extended it I can create my own instance and get the required functionaluity

Comment: so Program:lol so I can make a program with all the methods of lol already available

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as the method definition in the supertype is accessable to the subtype (and to the code that wants to invoke the method).

Here's some sample code. Whether the method definition in the subtype or supertype is invoked is dependent upon how the override is defined:

```
public abstract class AbstractSupertype
{
  public void Alpha()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "AbstractSupertype.Alpha()" ) ;
    return ;
  }
  public abstract void Bravo() ;
  public virtual  void Charlie()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "AbstractSupertype.Charlie()" ) ;
    return ;
  }
}

public class ConcreteSubtype : AbstractSupertype
{
  public new void Alpha()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "ConcreteSubtype.Alpha()" ) ;
  }
  public override void Bravo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "ConcreteSubtype.Bravo()" ) ;
  }
  public override void Charlie()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "ConcreteSubtype.Charlie()" ) ;
  }
}
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    ConcreteSubtype   subTypeInstanceReference   = new ConcreteSubtype() ;
    AbstractSupertype superTypeInstanceReference = subTypeInstanceReference ;

    subTypeInstanceReference.Alpha()     ; // invokes subtype's method
    superTypeInstanceReference.Alpha()   ; // invokes supertype's method

    subTypeInstanceReference.Bravo()     ; // invokes subtype's method
    superTypeInstanceReference.Bravo()   ; // invokes subtype's method

    subTypeInstanceReference.Charlie()   ; // invokes subtype's method
    superTypeInstanceReference.Charlie() ; // invokes subtype's method

    return ;
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you invoke AbstractSupertype.Charlie?

Comment: From within your subtype, you sez, `base.Charlie()`. The keyword modifier `override` means that your subtype is *replacing* (specializing) the parent type's method/property and that that specialization exists even when an instance is upcast. In contrast, the `new` modifier specifies that your replacing (hiding) the parent implementation and on being upcast, the instance should revert to the parent behavior. It should be noted that when a method or property is defined with `override`, the parent's version ceases to be publicly available.